# How to write a Query to get sum total of each order in the list joining 3 tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am just learning ASP.net MVC 5 and I have a complicated query that I cannot get right in my controller.  I need to show a list of upcoming milestones and display with it the total amount of money that has been spend on the campaign that each Milestone represents.  The campaigns are in one table, the milestones in another, the services in another and the orders in another.

The Milestones, Campaigns and Services are all tied by CampaignId.  The Orders are tied to the Services table by ServiceId.  I am using code first and entity framework, but I cannot figure out how to write the query to assemble the list to send to the view.

This is the View

@model IEnumerable

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "LookUpMilestones";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdminDashboard.cshtml";
}
<div id="adminDash" class="col-md-8 col-xs-10 adminDash light-grey">
<p class="lead text-uppercase">More Upcoming Milestones</p>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Next Milestones</td>
            <td>Pledges $ In</td>
            <td>Milestone $</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CampaignId)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TermEndDate)</td>
                <td>pledges$</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TargetAmount)</td>
                <td>

                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "../CampaignsFSC/MyDetails/", new { id = item.CampaignId }) 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

I need help writing the query that I an pass to the view to loop through and fill in the fields.  I can get it all except the total amount for each milestone because that amount is stored in the Orders table, but there is not a direct path.

```
[dbo].[MilestoneDetails] (
[id]                       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[MilestoneId]              INT            NOT NULL,
[CampaignId]               INT            NOT NULL,
[UserId]                   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL


[dbo].[Order] (
[OrderId]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[UserId]              NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[ServiceId]           INT            NOT NULL,
[PaymentProfileId]    INT            NOT NULL,
[OrderDate]           DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[Amount]              REAL           NOT NULL

[dbo].[Service] (
[ServiceId]        INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CampaignId]       INT             NOT NULL,
[Cost]             DECIMAL (19, 4) NOT NULL,
[Description]      NVARCHAR (500)  NOT NULL,
[DeliveryDate]     DATETIME        NOT NULL,
[DeliveryDesc]     NVARCHAR (500)  NOT NULL,
[MaxQuantity]      INT             NULL,
[ApprovedDate]     DATETIME        NULL,
[DisplayOrder]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[Status]           INT             NULL
```

So this is my attempt to put it all together in the controller:

```
public ActionResult LookUpMilestone()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

var Milestones = (from m in db.MilestoneDetails                                      
orderby m.TermEndDate ascending
where m.TermEndDate >= System.DateTime.Now
 select new {
     m.CampaignId,
     totalOrders = (from serv in db.Services 
                     on m.CampaignId equals serv.CampaignId
                       join ord in db.Orders on serv.ServiceId equals       
ord.ServiceId).Sum(ord => ord.Amount))}
).Distinct();

return View("LookUpMilestones", Milestones);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with asp.net or mvc...  it's strictly an entity-framework and linq query problem.  The fact you're using it in mvc is irrelevant to the problem.  It would also help if you actually said what your problem is.  "cannot get it right" doesn't tell us anything.  Are there errors? do you get the wrong data?  What's the structure of the data?

Comment: I have no idea how to write it.  Visual Studio is giving me errors such as: anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name, Invalid expression term 'Join', syntax error..  I just don't know how to write it correctly.  It all starts falling apart in the "totalorders =" section.

Comment: @user3732031 Give us some pseudocode or explanation of what you're trying to retrieve. Or at least, some inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I've added more information.  Let me know if it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

yes you're on the right track.  You just seem to be having some syntactical issues

```
select new {
 m.CampaignId,
 totalOrders = (from serv in db.Services 
                join ord in db.Orders on serv.ServiceId equals ord.ServiceId
                where m.CampaignId == serv.CampaignId
                   && ord.UserId == m.UserId  //this line might not be correct depending on what UserId is used for
                select ord
               ).Sum(ord => ord.Amount)
}
```

oh and in your query, just to optimize, put the where clause before the orderby clause to reduce your memory footprint

And I'm not seeing TermEndDate or TargetAmount in your db schema anywhere or i'd help fill in those properties